# What's the meaning of the SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider?

Tags: java, ssh, sshd, apache-mina

1. In the Apache MiNa sshd interface, what's the meaning of the following interface?
   Is the `key.ser` a private key or public key or others?

   ```
    sshd.setKeyPairProvider(new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider(new File("d:\\", "key.ser")));
   ```
2. `The sshd.setPublickeyAuthenticator#authenticate` is used to check whether the public key is valid, the `UserAuthPublicKey#Auth` is used to check the signature is valid, right?

   ```
    public interface PublickeyAuthenticator {
        boolean authenticate(String username, PublicKey key, ServerSession session);
    }
   ```

Comment: [TODO Add javadoc](https://mina.apache.org/sshd-project/apidocs/org/apache/sshd/server/keyprovider/SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider.html) :)

Comment: Thanks, for question 2, do you know how to trigger the PublickeyAuthenticator? Seems now the password Authenticator is always triggered by default.